# pls pls help me understand how Console.WriteLine() work

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, console.writeline

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num, reverse = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number : ");
            num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (num != 0)
            {
                reverse = reverse * 10;
                reverse = reverse + num % 10;
                num = num / 10;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Reverse of Entered Number is : "+reverse);

        }
    }
}
```

I can grasp at the concept of the previous values of reverse accumulating during the iterations of the loop but why doesnt WriteLine() also output the string "Reverse of Entered Number is: " 3 times? I know it somewhat happens if I enter it in the loop body but the reverse output is still:

```
blah blah blah: 3 // I understand this
"          "  : 32 // I thought this was going to output 2
"          "  : 321 // while this outputs 1
```

Why is the "+ reverse" bit the only command executed? and not the whole line?

im sorry if this is a very basic or dumb question, its really bothering me had to create a SO account for it.

Comment: edited. Im expecting 1 as the output and I get 321 instead(which is actually, correct). Im trying to figure out how it came to be so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's walk through the program:

It starts with the variables `num` and `reverse` are initialized to `0`;

```
    int num, reverse = 0;
```

Now, a prompt is written to the console and `Console.ReadLine()` is used to read input from the user, which is parsed as an integer into the variable of `num`:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number : ");
    num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

For this example, let's assume the user entered the value `123`.

Now, the application will loop as long as `num` doesn't get set to `0`

```
    while (num != 0)
    {
```

Inside the loop, the value of `reverse` is multiplied by `10`.  The first time through, this will still be `0`, since `0 * 10` is `0`.

```
        reverse = reverse * 10;
```

This is followed by adding `num` modulus `10` to `reverse`. Basically, this will return the last digit of whatever number the user entered.  So if the user entered `123`, this will be set to `3` the first time through the loop.

```
        reverse = reverse + num % 10;
```

Now, the user's entered value stored in `num` is devided by `10`. Since it's an `int`, fractional values are truncated, so `123` becomes `12`.

```
        num = num / 10;
```

We now restart the loop, but with `num` set to `12` and `reverse` set to `3`.

At the top of the loop, `reverse` gets multiplied by `10` again, so it's new value is `30`.

Then we add the last digit of `num`, which is `2`, making `reverse` set to `32`.

Followed by dropping the last digit of `num`, making it `1`.

Once more, we loop, since `num` still doesn't equal `0`, this time with `num` set to `1` and `reverse` set to `32`.

At the top of the loop, `reverse` gets multiplied by `10` again, so it's new value is `320`.

Then we add the last digit of `num`, which is `1`, making `reverse` set to `321`.

Followed by dropping the last digit of `num`, making it `0`.

This time, `num` *does* equal `0`, so the loop ends.

```
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Reverse of Entered Number is : "+reverse);
```

The program completes by printing the string `"Reverse of Entered Number is : "` followed by the final value of `reverse`.

Comment: thank you! that was an amazing dissection I was honestly wrong with my execution of the addition and modulus. thanks a bunch! your breakdown helped me with my stupidity